# Customize in call and out call app in android

Tags: android

I want to customize the incoming call screen of the android.So i just create an activity for that with a broadcast receiver which gives the state of the phone with TelephonyManager class.But I want that my activity should launch instead of default activity of the phone.

Looking for some help